# How to checkout to a commit after it gets squashed?

Tags: git, gitlab, squash

During merge I use both `Delete source branch when merge request is accepted` and `Squash commits when merge request is accepted` options.

[image: Both options are enabled]

Gitlab does his job perfectly: It squash commits to the single one and merge it to the target branch.

[image: Squashing works as expected]

But it also keeps original commits - you can see them in `Commits` tab of merge request page:

[image: The "Commits" tab]

I want to be able to checkout to these commits. But in new cloned repository, git can't find them by hash:

```
$ git checkout c8ad8edf
error: pathspec 'c8ad8edf' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

I think this happens because `git clone` gets only commits that can be reach from the initial commit. But GitLab stores this information - I can view info of any commit in browser:

[image: Unreachable commits can be viewed using GitLab web interface]

So how can I checkout to these commits?

Comment: "*I think this happens because git clone gets only commits that can be reach from the initial commit*" -> No. Reachability works the other way round: git sees all commits reachable from existing refs (tags, branches, reflogs, stash entries), working backwards through ancestry, until initial commit (or initial commits, because there can be more than one)

Comment: If you cannot get it, you can try to create a branch on git lab and then you will be able to find it

Comment: Have you fetched the changes as well? `git fetch --all`

Comment: This is graph problem. As long as there are some tags/branches or chills which are tagged or pointed by any branch, commit will be visible. If you see commits then something must keep them alive in a history graph. Also git philosophy is do not delete anything. Physical deletion happens form time to time when commits are not reachable and are old. So for a quite long time you can checkout "deleted" commit if you are able to find it (for example using `git reflog`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fetch the `refs/merge-requests/$id/head` ref, where `$id` is the numerical ID of the merge request (3 in your case, from your screenshots): see [Checkout merge requests locally through the head ref](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/reviews/#checkout-merge-requests-locally-through-the-head-ref). Note that in GitLab 13.4 and newer, that ref is deleted 14 days after the MR is merged or closed.

```
git fetch origin refs/merge-requests/3/head
git checkout FETCH_HEAD
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. Is there any way to prevent GitLab from delete that ref after 14 days?

Comment: From reading the merge request where this "feature" was added (linked in the GitLab doc), no, it does not look like it's easily possible. It's mentioned that the removed refs are kept under `/refs/keep-around/` on the GitLab server, but since these refs are not hidden, it's not possible (at least easily) to fetch them (but see ["Security" in `git-fetch(1)`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#_security))...

Comment: ...  But with some automation, you could push a refs somewhere else than under `/refs/merge-requests/`, while the ref is still available (say under `/refs/mr/` or whatever you want to call it). GitLab won't touch it there and it should stay for as long as you like.

Comment: "but since these refs are not hidden, " that should read "since these refs are hidden", can't edit my comment anymore...